# Idiomatic way to modify a member variable

Tags: haskell

I know Haskell isn't OO so it isn't strictly a 'member variable'.

```
data Foo = Foo {
    bar :: Int,
    moo :: Int,
    meh :: Int,
    yup :: Int
}

modifyBar (Foo b m me y) = (Foo b' m me y)
    where b' = 2
```

This is how my code looks at the moment. The problem is I am now making data types with 16 or more members. When I need to modify a single member it results in very verbose code. Is there a way around this?

Comment: You don't modify anything. You create a new, different value.

Comment: If your data type has 16 members, chances are some of them could be grouped into a new data type.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
modifyBar foo = foo { bar = 2 }
```

---

This syntax will copy `foo`, and then modify the `bar` field of that copy to 2. This could be naturally extended to more fields, so you don't need to write that `modifyBar` function at all.

(See http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/code-case-study-parsing-a-binary-data-format.html#id625467)

Answer (score 5):

Haskell's "record syntax" that @KennyTM shows is the built-in way to do this, though keep in mind that it's still just a way of constructing a new value based on the old one.

There are some annoying limitations to record syntax, though, particularly that the form used to "modify" a single item in a record aren't first-class entities in the language, so you can't abstract over them and pass them around the way you'd do with a regular function.

An alternative is using [a library such as `fclabels`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/fclabels) which provides similar functionality, using Template Haskell to auto-generate accessor functions instead of built-in syntax. The result is often much nicer, with the downside that you now have a dependency on TH....

Comment: Forgive my ignorance since it seems like a common idea, but why is a dependency on TH bad?

Comment: @Davorak: I think mostly because it's bulky and potentially less portable. It feels kind of silly when you're compiling something and GHC spends more time loading all the dependencies and whatnot than it does compiling your actual code. TH gets this in particular because it tends to show up for little three-line metaprogramming convenience utilities.